# How nested method call works

Tags: java, methods

Can anybody explain this how this line of code works:

`Rational sum = a.add(b).add(c);`

I don't understand how object b (which is an argument) is receiving a method?

Comment: look up "method chaining". And object b isn't receiving a method. It's being passed into a method as a parameter.

Answer (score 4):

This is called [method chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining). The method `add()` actually returns a reference of the currently modified object or a new object of the same type on which the method was invoked. Say suppose the object referred to by `a` is a [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) , when you invoke [a.add(b)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#add(java.math.BigInteger)) , it returns a `BigInteger` object whose value is `a+b` , and hence you can invoke `.add(c)` on that object again.

```
 Rational sum = a.add(b).add(c);
 // is equivalent to
 Rational temp = a.add(b);
 Rational sum = temp.add(c);
```

Method chaining is not required. It only potentially improves readability and reduces the amount of source code. It is the core concept behind building a [fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).

A sample illustration:

[image]

This practice is used mostly in [Builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern), you can find this pattern in API itself in [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) class.

> I don't understand how object b (which is an argument) is receiving a method?

No your understanding is wrong , `a.add(b)` means you are invoking method `add()` on object `a` and passing it a reference of object `b` . The resultant object which the method `a.add(b)` returns is of the same type as `a` , and then in succession you call the method `.add(c)` on the returned object passing a reference of object `c` to that method.

Comment: Is there a technical limit to chaining depth set by the JLS, compiler, or language?

Comment: @hexafraction I don't know of any , need to research .

Comment: There certainly is a *intelligibility* limit!

Answer (score 1):

[Its fluent chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface)

> Each method in the chain has to return a class or an interface. The next method in the chain has to be a part of the returned class.

in your case   `a.add(b)`  returning some calss/interface  and then calling   `add(c)`  on that  and that method returns your `sum`